# Mass retagging, minor gripe

Tags: feature-request

Dheer worked through a large number of questions today, fixing their tags.

That's probably a good thing. But it does mess up all the most-recently-touched information.

It's a one-time nuisance, but it might be worth asking SE's developers whether there's a way to make administrivial actions "silent" as far as the recent-activity sort is concerned.

Comment: Didn't realise that the question gets bumped.

Answer (score 5):

Nearly 260 this month. 
Personally, I find the "bump on edit" to be more of a problem than benefit. I've seen new users without full edit privileges offer what I think is a trivial edit, and aside from hitting my approval queue, I think about the bump.

In this case, I think there's a benefit to be had by Dheer's efforts, as future members will find it easier to use tags to get information they seek.

On reading the first few posts Ganesh' link produced, it seems there's been no answer, just multiple discussion threads.

Update - One solution is to [bookmark by newest question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest). This will avoid the bumped edited posts.

Answer (score 3):

This has been extensively discussed before on Meta Stack Exchange:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=retagging+bumps+questions

I didn't manage to draw any concrete conclusions from those threads, but I guess that it would be a fair amount of effort to get a change and is probably not worth it for a relatively low volume site like ours.

Answer (score 2):

I guess given the amount of discussion on Meta Stack Exchange as linked by Ganesh, there is no real solution. It seems this would be on low priority for a fix from Stack Exchange.

Given this it makes more sense that tag edits be done at a slower pace, maybe not more than half a dozen per day. I guess there are very few users [probably just me] who are doing Mass tag edits and an restrain can easily be achieved. This should resolve the bumps to few question and at the same time achieve the goal of right tagging, albeit at a slower pace.

Answer (score 2):

I'll add a new answer to this, as it seems to be a problem at the moment:

Here's an example: [Powerball Winnings: Annuity or Lump Sum](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/84074/44232), adding a low-count tag to a question marked as duplicate with 0 answers.

In my opinion, such edits, done en-masse, do nothing to increase value for the site, and instead make the home page unusable.

Answer (score 2):

> it might be worth asking SE's developers whether there's a way to make administrivial actions "silent" as far as the recent-activity sort is concerned.

It looks like there is a way. Apparently, questions that are locked while being edited (by a diamond moderator) aren't bumped to the top of the front page. It's a couple extra steps, but it might be worth considering.

See [What bad tags in need of burnination do we still have hanging around?](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/7880/58408) on Meta Server Fault, where HopelessN00b wrote:

> Either way, questions that are locked for historical significance can be ♦-edited (therefore, retagged) without bumping them to the top of the active list... so I'll be temporarily locking questions I retag to minimize disruptions.

Comment: Glad to see this. Of course, that's only if a mod is tag editing. The last few rounds of edits that sparked this question were done by kind regular members.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Indeed, locking isn't available to all users (and I think we should be glad for that).

Answer (score 1):

I can only speak as a new user at this particular SE (though I have long experience with others).

I share keshlam's gripe with this practice of mass re-tagging questions. I like to read new questions and answers, and rely on the site's inherent front page sorting to show me the latest posts, be it questions or answers.

On MathematicsSE or StackOverflow, this wouldn't be a problem, because new content blazes in by the second, but for MoneySE, I feel like this should be moderated internally.

And besides, all these single-tag additions; are they really *that* important?

This wouldn't be a problem if it happened only once, but it seems to be a trend.

Answer (score 1):

I guess a related point is that this site seems to use tags differently than other SE sites (at least the ones that I read).  For example, a tax question is not consider "complete" here unless the jurisdiction is provided as a tag, even if the jurisdiction is specified in the text of the question.  I don't see that type of thing so much on other sites - People do edit tags, but they don't ever seem to be considered an essential element of the question itself.  For better or worse, that would seem to make this site more prone to retagging and whatever negatives go with it.  To the extent that the site is non-standard in addition to probably relatively low volume, that may go with the other answers about it not being worth the trouble for SE to fix.