# Useless edits bumping old questions

Tags: discussion

It seems that one user has been on a roll this morning editing tons of old questions and basically filling the front page with this. This type of behavior makes the site quite unusable as real, current questions are being buried so he/she can add a hyphen to a tag for a question asked and answered in 2014.

Comment: It's not just this morning - it's been happening for over a week now. I'm not opposed to adding tags to improve searchability, but you are right that it does add a lot of noise to the "active questions" view

Comment: @DStanley Ah, I must have just not noticed before but right now the front page is absolutely dominated by this. The first 26 questions all fall into this.

Comment: Related question https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2253/mass-retagging-minor-gripe I guess self restraint is the way to go for now.

Answer (score 2):

The question asked here isn't a question, but a statement.

The issue is systemic, an edit bumps a question to the from page, as does a new answer. This is how all of SE is coded.

[Privileges](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) are granted based on member rep. Editing with no need for approval is granted at 2000. There have been kind members who offered edits, laundry lists of them, and it's taken time to approve them all. At times, I'd pace, so they weren't filling the first page. In this case, the member is 2000+ rep and is free to do this.

If I ran the world, these would either (A) not bump, and would not be even noticed, or (B) throttle, by either (B1) limiting members to X edits per day, or (B2) prioritizing, so edits on older posts don't go though at a rate of more than X per day. But I don't, and this question seems to have been discussed already, at a higher level.

Update - One solution is to [bookmark by newest question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest). This will avoid the bumped edited posts.

Comment: Is there any way to, for example, provide a friendly comment to an individual doing these types of edits, to indicate that the community would prefer volume restraint?

Comment: I've asked this on a moderator board within SE. Just now, in response to your post.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: If I am not wrong, the edits are intentional (and with good purpose) to bump old good question on main page so that those can be better answered.

Comment: I think you are wrong. As other members have complained, these actions turn a first page of otherwise new questions into a review of old ones. Doing a disservice to those newer questions.

Comment: Yes; I realized I was wrong. Duplicate target discusses about improving quality of old questions. And, this process is going on since Feb-2018. I agree about issues it is causing by hiding new questions though. In fact, that is the reason why I came here on meta to learn why.