# New tag suggestion: cohabitation

Tags: discussion, tags

[How to handle shared mortgage payment if one person can't pay their share?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/115374/how-to-handle-shared-mortgage-payment-if-one-person-cant-pay-their-share) is one of many "my boy/girlfriend and I bought a house together, and then we broke up and he/she owns 50% of the property, but now isn't paying his/her share of the mortgage" questions.

We need a tag to be able to easily find these, so I suggest `cohabitation`.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search on “shared” gives 4,000+ results. I’m sure the new tag would apply to many dozens.

I’d kindly request that, if you plan to add this tag to multiple questions, to do so only a few per day, so they don’t flood “page 1” and push new questions off.

Comment: Can I just add new tags on my own?

Comment: At your level of rep, I believe you can. Worst case, it goes into my mod queue for approval.

Comment: On the other hand, doing them all at once will mean the pain/inconvenience/etc is short-lived.

Comment: See [Mass retagging, minor gripe](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2253/mass-retagging-minor-gripe) .  This is not a 'rule', just a polite request. It doesn't happen too often. A new tag, and member wishing to update to add that tag to 100+ questions....